# golang/gorm: api end point returning only last record

Tags: go, go-gorm

Hi I am learning to use golang right now, and there is an api end point, where I want to return all the existing users in the database, however my query is returning only last user.

```
base.go < responsible for establishing db conns
import (
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite")
var db *gorm.DB //database
func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
return db
}

models.go < responsible for data abstractions

type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Token    string `json:"token";sql:"-"`
}
func GetAllUsers() *Account {

acc := &Account{}
rows, err := GetDB().Raw("select * from accounts").Rows()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error")
}
for rows.Next() {
    GetDB().ScanRows(rows, &acc)
}
return acc
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filling the same `acc` struct through each iteration. You are also passing a pointer to a pointer of `Account`. Try adding a slice to hold all the accounts.

```
func GetAllUsers() []*Account {
    accs := []*Account{}
    rows, err := GetDB().Raw("select * from accounts").Rows()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        acc := &Account{}
        GetDB().ScanRows(rows, acc)
        accs = append(accs, acc)
    }
    return accs
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any special need, better to use default gorm approach to retrieve entries for some model:

```
func GetAllUsers() []Account {
    var accs []Account
    res := GetDB().Find(&accs)

    if res.Error != nil {
        // Query is failed, handle error as you like.
    }

    return accs
}
```